# Save panels location after closing in a Netbeans Java application

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

I have a Java application developed in Netbeans 8.0.2. I would like to save the position of the panels in this application so when I close it and open it again it will remember if the "Projects tab" is on the right side or in the left side for example.

Any idea how could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried writing the corresponding coordinates (x, y for an absolute layout) to a file and loading that file at startup if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Netbeans Platform application should do this automatically. For a regular Swing or JavaFX application your on your own to save positions to a file  and restore the positions after reading the file.

One thing to note however about the Netbeans Platform application is that a clean and build will delete your saved positions. This is not a problem for your users that will never be expected to rebuild your application from source but it could explain your not seeing the positions saved as you do testing and development.